# Entity Framework Cast not supported

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i hope anybody can help me with this. I use EF6 with TPC (Table per concrete class). There are many tables that are revision save, means every row in the table has the same ID, but multiple versions. One version is the current version (e.g.). 
Table student sample:

```
Id  Version     Name        CurrentVersion
1   1           Murtin      false
1   2           Martin      true
2   1           Reinold     true
```

I use inheritance in my models. The base of all models is EntityBase

```
abstract class EntityBase: IEntityBase
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

For all tables that are revision save i use the next base class

```
abstract class RevisionBase : EntityBase, IRevisionBase
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Version { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool CurrentVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Now my table i work with, of course students

```
class Student: RevisionBase
{
    [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

So the following code is easy and working

```
new DBContext().Student.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Id=5 && s.CurrentVersion=true)
```

For uniformly data processing i want to use always the same base method for loading. So i have uniformly error handling and logging. This general get method should always load the current version, if its a versioned table.

```
    private TEntity GeneralGet<TEntity>(int id) where TEntity : EntityBase
    {
        using (var ctx = GetContext())
        {
            if (typeof(IRevisionBase).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
            {
                var allResultsId = ctx.Set<TEntity>().Where(l => l.Id == id);
                var result = allResultsId.ToList().Cast<IRevisionBase>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.CurrentVersion);
                return result as TEntity;
            }
            else        // ansonsten, bei nicht versionierten Objekten
            {
                var result = ctx.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(l => l.Id == id);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is completely working, but unfortunately i have to load all rows of the same id and filter the current version in memory. (ToList loads all rows with the given id.)

Are there any better ways?

I dont want this "ToList" there. What i need is either a cast to check my current version or maybe mix method chain way and a hard coded filter string. (not nice, but much better than this) I know that this table has a column CurrentVersion. I want to check this before loading all records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF does no like casting (and interfaces in general) and C# does not allow "casting" types.

Still what you are asking is possible. I see at least two (probably not perfect, but working) options:

**(1)** Create a generic constrained method like this:

```
static IQueryable<TEntity> WhereCurrentVersion<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> source)
    where TEntity : class, IRevisionBase
{
    return source.Where(e => e.CurrentVersion);
}
```

and call it via reflection or dynamically:

```
private TEntity GeneralGet<TEntity>(int id) where TEntity : EntityBase
{
    using (var ctx = GetContext())
    {
        var result = ctx.Set<TEntity>().Where(e => e.Id == id);
        if (result is IQueryable<IRevisionBase>)
            result = WhereCurrentVersion((dynamic)result);
        return result.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

**(2)** Build filter expression dynamically:

```
private TEntity GeneralGet<TEntity>(int id) where TEntity : EntityBase
{
    using (var ctx = GetContext())
    {
        var result = ctx.Set<TEntity>().Where(e => e.Id == id);
        if (result is IQueryable<IRevisionBase>)
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");
            var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
                Expression.Property(parameter, nameof(IRevisionBase.CurrentVersion)),
                parameter);
            result = result.Where(predicate);
        }
        return result.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great Ivan, thank you. I have checked the first version and it is really working. Only one sql statement is sent to the DB. This sql statement contains both where conditions. Now i will try the second way just for myself to learn...

Comment: wow, second way is also working! unfortunately i can only vote once!

Comment: by the way, after i checked the second way, i like it more than the first one. i dont need another method, so i take this, but i'll keep the first in comment, to remind me later.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a model containing properties and then You can use a Cast Extension method to cast into appropriate type. Then do the simple LINQ.

```
public static T Cast<T>(this Object myobj)
{
    Type objectType = myobj.GetType();
    var dx = myobj.GetType().GetProperties();
    Type target = typeof(T);
    var x = Activator.CreateInstance(target, false);
    var z = from source in objectType.GetMembers().ToList()
            where source.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property
            select source;
    var d = from source in target.GetMembers().ToList()
            where source.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property
            select source;
    List<MemberInfo> members = d.Where(memberInfo => d.Select(c => c.Name).ToList().Contains(memberInfo.Name)).ToList();
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo;
    object value;
    foreach (var memberInfo in members)
    {
        propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(memberInfo.Name);                
        if (Array.Exists(dx, a => a.Name == propertyInfo.Name))
        {
            value = myobj.GetType().GetProperty(memberInfo.Name).GetValue(myobj, null);
            propertyInfo.SetValue(x, value, null);
        }
    }
    return (T)x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that idea, but this can't be a useful way. this is a lot of reflection code and a lot of new instances are also created. i only want to check a column i actually have in my EF filter...

Answer (score 0):

```
var tmp = LocalDB.Article.Select(A => A.Matricule).ToArray();
```

You can do something like this, where you'll have an array of the values you want exactly, then you can add them to another array or list using whatever method or type you want...

or you could just from the start do something like this

```
var list = new List<T>();
foreach(var item in LocalDB.Article.Select(A => A.Matricule).ToArray()) 
list.Add(/*Transform item to your wanted type*/);
```